# getting selected text in current window

Tags: linux, x11

I'm trying to build a script that will add the currently selected text to the end of a file. So far it looks like cat selected_text >> quotes.txt.

Is there any way, either in command line or in C/C++ to get the currently selected text from the currently active window?

Comment: By the way, you are technically asking for the X11 selection. Highlighted text is not a Linux-specific thing.

Comment: @chrisaycock Looks that way. I'll add an X11 tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [xclip](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip) command

This command operates on X11 selections (the *middle-click paste* clipboard). It can be used to retrieve the last block of text that was selected using the mouse.

Comment: Actually, `xclip` allows you to work with the three X selections: primary, secondary and clipboard. The "middle-click" one (primary) is the default one but it's possible to switch it using the `-selection` flag.

Answer (score 4):

[xsel](https://github.com/kfish/xsel) is a command line tool for getting selected text, If the last text you have selected is in your current window, you will get it with command:

```
xsel
```